# Why is my mat-error only shown if I click two times on button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a search bar that retrieves data from my database, whenever the search is successful the data retrieved populates a mat table, so far so good and it works.

The problem I'm facing is when that search is unable to retrieve anything from the database because the user provided invalid information.

When I provide data to the input form and the HTTP Response fails, a mat-error is supposed to trigger instantly, however that only happens if I click on the search button two times.

This is the code I have:

**MyComponent.component.ts**

```
public inputForm: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
  this.inputForm = new FormControl('');
}

private searchForReturnByOrderNumber(value) {
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderNumber(value).subscribe((returnOrdNrData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdNrData).length !== 0) {
          this.returns = returnOrdNrData;
          this.setReturns();
        } else {
          this.openDialog(orderNrData, returnOrdNrData);
        }
      }, error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.openDialog(orderNrData, []);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
    }
  }, error => {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  });
}

private isInputInvalid() {
  if (this.inputForm.hasError('invalid')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

private getErrorMessage() {
  return this.inputForm.invalid ? 'Invalid Search!' : '';
}
```

**MyComponent.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2"></div>

  <div class="col-8 search-div">

    <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Search</mat-label>

      <input matInput class="search-input" placeholder="Ex: EU030327" [formControl]="inputForm" #searchInput>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isInputInvalid()">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>

    <span matSuffix>
      <button mat-flat-button class="search-btn" color="accent" [disabled]="isInputInvalid()"
        (click)="searchForReturnByOrderNumber(searchInput.value)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>

  </div>

  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

If I input some invalid data (data that is not present in the database) and press my "search-btn", my mat error won't appear, only if I press the button again.

I've debugged this and the code correctly enters the intended code:

```
} else {
  this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
}
```

It sets the inputForm as invalid but the mat-error won't appear until I click the button again...

Anyone knows what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem so I'll post my solution for anyone who might bump into this issue...

I created a boolean `isInputInvalid` and set it to true by default. Whenever I press my search button, the HTTP request is executed and, depending on the response, the `isInputInvalid` boolean is set to true or false. If the HTTP response is invalid I set it to true, if it's valid I set it to false.

Then, if the boolean is true, I set my Form Control as invalid.

In my HTML file I surrounded my input with a `<form>` and created a `[formGroup]`. For error validation I set the `*ngIf` inside `<mat-error>` equal to `searchForm.controls['inputForm'].invalid`.

Here is my code:

**MyComponent.component.ts**

```
private searchForm: FormGroup;
private isInputInvalid: boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
    inputForm: new FormControl('')
  });
}

private searchForReturnByOrderNumber(value) {
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderNumber(value).subscribe((returnOrdNrData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdNrData).length !== 0) {
          this.isInputInvalid = false;
          this.returns = returnOrdNrData;
          this.setReturns();
        } else {
          this.isInputInvalid = false;
          this.openDialog(orderNrData, returnOrdNrData);
        }
      }, error => {
        this.isInputInvalid = true;
      });
    } else {
      this.isInputInvalid = true;
    }
  }, error => {
    this.isInputInvalid = true;
  });

  if(this.isInputInvalid){
    this.searchForm.controls['inputForm'].setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  }
}

private getErrorMessage() {
  return this.searchForm.controls['inputForm'].invalid ? 'Invalid Search!' : '';
}
```

**MyComponent.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2"></div>

  <div class="col-8 search-div">
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
      <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Search</mat-label>

        <input matInput class="search-input" placeholder="Ex: EU030327" formControlName="inputForm" #searchInput>
        <mat-error *ngIf="searchForm.controls['inputForm'].invalid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>

      </mat-form-field>
    </form>

    <span matSuffix>
      <button mat-flat-button class="search-btn" color="accent" [disabled]="searchForm.controls['inputForm'].invalid"
        (click)="searchForReturnByOrderNumber(searchInput.value)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>

  </div>

  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition of your `*ngIf` is not recalculated.
I think you can replace it by something like :

```
<mat-error *ngIf="inputForm?.hasError('invalid')">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
```

Also, you don't need the condition inside the `getErrorMessage()` method. The message will only be displayed if you have an error to start with.
You might have a race condition leading this method to return an empty string. Try simplifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried that but I still have to click two times on the button for the mat-error to show...

Comment: Can you post the initialization of your `inputForm` ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you also check what the `getErrorMessage()` method returns ?

Comment: I changed it to this `<mat-error *ngIf="inputForm?.hasError('invalid')">Invalid Search!</mat-error>` but I still have the same problem...
I knew it wasn't a problem with `getErrorMessage()` because my search button turns disabled when the search is invalid and that only happens when I click on it two times as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does your mat-error have to be ngIf*? Can it not just use ngClass?

Would it not work if you had a property of isInputInvalid, set to false intially, and if your search method returns 'invalid', then set your isInputInvalid property to true?

Then you can just use ngClass:

```
<mat-error [ngClass]="{'your-class': isInputInvalid}">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
```

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<mat-error [ngClass="{'show-mat-error': isInputInvalid}">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
```

TS - you need an 'isInputInvalid' property to change:

```
isInputInvalid: boolean = false;
```

TS - you need to implement a method along these lines to change the value of 'isInputInvalid':

```
if (this.inputForm.hasError('invalid')) {
   this.isInputInvalid = true;
} else {
  this.isInputInvalid = false;
}
```

CSS:

```
mat-error {
display: none;
}

.show-mat-error {
display: block;
}
```

I would probably also do something like this in your component so that the error is hidden each time a user navigates to the page:

```
    constructor(private router: Router) {

  router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {

    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.isInputInvalid = false;
    }
  });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I use *ngIf because I only want to show the mat-error when my search is invalid...
I've never used the ngClass binding, what am I supposed to put in the place of 'your-class'?

Comment: If you style your mat-error to display:none, then 'your-class' would be a CSS class with 'display:block', and when 'isInputInvalid' gets set to true, the CSS class would be added to mat-error and the previous style of display:none would be set to display:block and mat-error would render.

Here is the angular resource:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description

It's worth looking at ngClass and ngStyle if you haven't used them yet, they're useful. Hope this helps!

Note, 'your-class' can be any CSS class you have in the component CSS template, and contain any styles needed

Comment: I'm not sure I did it the right way because it's not working...
I did this: `<mat-error class="hide-mat-error" [ngClass]="{'display-mat-error': inputInvalid}">Invalid Search!</mat-error>`

and in my CSS I have the following classes: 
`.hide-mat-error{
 display: none;
}

.display-mat-error{
 display: block;
}`

In my .ts file I replaced `this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });` with `this.inputInvalid = true;`

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that all makes sense and helps!

Comment: I tried it but I'm not having any luck... The mat-error won't display instantly, I still have to press the button 2 times. I can't find anything online about using mat-error for http responses

Comment: I have an interesting situation... If I copy my code and put it in a MatDialog, the mat-error triggers instantly